# React-Native Child of object returns undefined despite it exists

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-iap

I am having a very basic but mind blowing issue that i cant figure out. Here is this:

***Short summary of problem***

I got `receipt` object coming from IAP, but cant get `productId` child. It returns `undefined` ? How can it happen ? receipt.productID returns undefined despite receipt object its ok and has a productId child which is not undefined. It should perfectly return me 'lite_plan' but it returns undefined?

```
  initIAP = () => {


RNIap.initConnection().then(() => {


  RNIap.flushFailedPurchasesCachedAsPendingAndroid().catch(() => {

  }).then(() => {

    console.log('open listener')
    
    this.purchaseUpdateSubscription = purchaseUpdatedListener((purchase: InAppPurchase | SubscriptionPurchase | ProductPurchase ) => {

      console.log('purchaseUpdatedListener', purchase);
      var receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
      if (receipt) {


       console.log('receipt >> ' + receipt)

       console.log('product id >> ' + receipt.productId)


         AsyncStorage.setItem('activeplan_local', receipt.productId).then(() => { 



.....
```

console output:

```
receipt >> {"orderId":"****","packageName":"com.****","productId":"lite_plan","purchaseTime":1617193622753,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"*****","autoRenewing":true,"acknowledged":false}


product id >> undefined
```

Can you show me the issue ?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
this.purchaseUpdateSubscription = purchaseUpdatedListener(async (purchase: InAppPurchase | SubscriptionPurchase | ProductPurchase ) => {

      console.log('purchaseUpdatedListener', purchase);
      // use const instead of var
      const receipt = await purchase.transactionReceipt;
      if (receipt) {

       console.log('receipt >> ' + receipt)

       console.log('product id >> ' + receipt.productId)

         AsyncStorage.setItem('activeplan_local', receipt.productId).then(() => {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still same. I also tried like const receipt2 = receipt inside the if  and receipt2.productId and still same. How strange is it right ? Its more like javascript issue so i edited the title.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution like this:

```
    var receiptObject = JSON.parse(receipt)
    var productId = JSON.parse(receipt).productId
```

Still could not figure out why i needed to parse receipt object. It was already an object. Strange but working this way.